# How to disable ctrl and alt press to open dropdown in jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Steps to reproduce:

- open http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox in IE9
- select Combobox in right side
- click in autocomplete box.
- press and release ctrl or alt key

Observed:

autocomplete dropdown menu is opened.

How to disable this opening so that only ctrl and alt key does not open dropdown box ?

**Update**

I tried

```
$(input).bind({
    keydown: function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
            return false;
          }
    }
 });
```

but this blocks all keys.

I noticed that if ctrl key is hold down dropdown menu disappears but if ctrl is released, it is opened again.

It looks like come event causes dropdown to re-opened.

Comment: what have you tried? Have you tried listen for the CTRL/ALT keydown event and than using e.preventDefault();

Comment: I tried to block ctlr/Alt presses but this blocks all keys. I updated question. It looks like a bug since widget contains code which must close dropdown like in usual select element button

Comment: try using it on the keypress event instead, also if it's blocking all the keys, than you probally have to return true if it isn't ctrl/alt

Comment: Dropdown is opened if ctrl key is released. Check in question blocks also Ctrl+Q etc key combinations. How to dedect if ctrl or alt is pressed without any other key?